# How can I save an image of the nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Is it possible somehow to save an image from the entire node window so that I can view the circuit in detail without having to go into the program? In addition to taking regular screenshots of course.

[image]

Comment: top menu > Window > Save Screenshot?

Comment: As @moonboots says, but use Window > Save Screenshot (Editor) and click in the node window to save an image of just that window.

Comment: Nope, the quality is too bad, besides, it will not be possible to take a screenshot of areas of the node window that do not fit on the screen.

Comment: Press Ctrl Spacebar to make the window full size?

Comment: https://github.com/b-init/PrintNodes

Comment: @quellenform you can give that as an answer

Comment: @quellenform this is exactly what I was looking for, although the plugin does not work on new versions

Comment: You can enable Nvidia DSR with factors allowing up to 4K resolution, to easily make a 4K screenshot on Full HD monitor. If you have an analog monitor, you can also set it to whatever resolution you want (**WARNING: no guarantee it won't break it, do at your own risk**), though it's harder to operate what's going on that monitor (could use OBS), I used this trick to capture 16K in the past… If you don't have an analog monitor, it's enough to have a dummy plug, **BUT BE CAREFUL DOING ONE YOURSELF, AS SHORT-CIRCUITING THE GPU MAY DESTROY IT**

Comment: @solo_GRV I just used v1.2 of it in Blender 3.6.1 without any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this deserves its own answer, but as far as I know there is no other answer to this question at the moment.

It is possible to create a screenshot of the shown window content with the function integrated in Blender via *Window > Save Screenshot (Editor)*, but this always shows exactly the existing window content with the shown resolution. ...nothing more.

As soon as you want to screenshot large node trees, this function is often not sufficient, as the resolution is also reduced.

The only possibility I know of at the moment is [PrintNodes](https://github.com/b-init/PrintNodes), an add-on that does this for you:

The handling is relatively simple:

- Download and install the latest release [here](https://github.com/b-init/PrintNodes/releases)
- Read the [manual](https://github.com/b-init/PrintNodes#usage)
- Use it (and hope you don't find a bug)

*All credit goes to the author of the extension.*